# Using binary sequences to define an injection from the set of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

I would appreciate help how to use binary sequences to define an injection from

$\{$permutations of $\mathbb{N}\}$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

I can see how to do this for a finite set of natural numbers. Just allocate the number of spaces to represent the largest number in the set in binary form and then, using $0$s where necessary to the left of the binary representation of the other elements to fill out that maximum number of spaces, place the binary representations in a string reflecting their positions under the permutation. This would be a $1$-to-$1$ mapping.

But I can't see how to do this for $\mathbb{N}$.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a boring way. Let the permutation be $a_1, a_2, \dots$. Then express each $a_i$ in unary, and create the number $$0.\underbrace{11\dots1}_{a_1}\ 0\ \underbrace{11\dots1}_{a_2}\ 0\dots$$

From this expression, one may extract the $n$th element $a_n$ of the sequence by searching for the $n-1$th and $n$th zero. (One could consider this to be a base-$2$ representation to satisfy the "use binary sequences" requirement.)

Comment: Thanks - I was stymied as to how to distinguish the various $a_{i}$. Do you actually need the decimal point after the leftmost $0$? Regards,

Comment: @Andrew You do need the number to be fractional, because otherwise it's trying to extend indefinitely far to the left so it's infinitely large. But you could, if you like, put any finite number of terms to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

With a map $f\colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$, we can associate the strictly increasing map $s\colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$, $n\mapsto n+\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)$ and with this the 
real number
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{-s(n)} $$
This gives us an injective map $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}\to \Bbb R$.

Comment: Pedantic point: the set of permutations of natural numbers is not the same as the set of sequences of natural numbers. But since the former is a subset of the latter, it doesn't change the 1-1 nature.

Comment: Thank you. Very instructive and I learned a lot from your answer. Please forgive me as I accepted Patrick's answer because of the "binary sequences" aspect. With regards,